# Understanding what FE_TONEAREST does

Tags: c++, c, c++11, floating-point

The gcc documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding.html), explains what FE_TONEAREST does:

> This is the default mode. It should be used unless there is a specific
> need for one of the others. In this mode results are rounded to the
> nearest representable value. If the result is midway between two
> representable values, the even representable is chosen. Even here
> means the lowest-order bit is zero.

Now, consider the below example:

```
printf("%.2f\n", 1.235); // nearest are 1.23 and 1.24, 1.24 should be chosen
printf("%.2f\n", 1.225); // nearest are 1.22 and 1.23, 1.22 should be chosen
```

Based on the documentation, I expect to get `1.24` and `1.22`. Instead, I get `1.24` and `1.23`.

What am I missing?

Comment: `1.23` and `1.22` are not necessarily equally "near" to `1.225` in `double` representation. FWIW, neither of these are representable values.

Comment: And regardless, `FE_TONEAREST` applies to internal floating point calculations and has very little to do with `printf` rounding.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: There is no reason for that; conversion from a binary floating-point format to a decimal numeral is an operation covered by IEEE-754 and should obey requests for directed rounding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.235 and 1.225 are not numbers in your program.

Your C implementation almost certainly uses the IEEE-754 “double precision” format for `double`, which is also called binary64. If it performs correctly rounded conversions to the nearest representable values, then the source text `1.235` is converted to the `double` 1.2350000000000000976996261670137755572795867919921875. When `printf` converts this to a decimal numeral with two decimal places, there is no tie; it is above 1.235, so the result is the numeral “1.24”.

The source text `1.225` is converted to the `double` 1.225000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625. When `printf` converts this to a decimal numeral with two decimal places, there is no tie; it is above 1.225, so the result is the numeral “1.23”.

Comment: thanks! can you elaborate on and probably give an example of a tie condition?

Comment: @cmutex: Every number in a binary floating-point format that is not an integer ends in 5 when converted to decimal. So, to get a tie, just format it with one fewer digit than it has in decimal. Formatting `1.235` with `%.51f` and `1.225` with `%.50f` will exercise the tied cases. Note that 50 digits is beyond what the C standard requires an implementation to support, so it may not use correct rounding. (E.g., past Windows .NET software only supports 17 digits. I do not know about current versions.) You could also use `.125`, `.375`, `.625`, and `.875` with `%.2f`.

Answer (score 2):

If you print 17 digits after the decimal, you'll get this:

```
1.23500000000000010
1.22500000000000009
```

So both are slightly more than the "expected" decimal representation, and so both round up.